# C# Discord Bot: How can I check if a user has said a specific phrase?

Tags: c#, command, bots, discord.net

So I'm trying to create a bot that responds to a certain line of text in my discord server. I want to check if my friend says "no u" (he says that a lot, he has the mentality of a five year old) and I want my bot to respond to this statement. I'm still relatively new to C# and have looked desperately everywhere for this answer. If you can help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried so far? It's much easier to help you that way.

Comment: As @ThomasFonn said, what is it you've got so far? Have you researched how to create a discord bot in C#, or is that your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout [this](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/blob/dev/docs/guides/getting_started/samples/intro/message.cs) example from the Discord.Net GitHub. Essentially you need to subscribe to the `MessageReceived` event and then reply based on the message.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

```
using System;
using Discord;

class Program
{
    static public DiscordClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        client = new DiscordClient(input =>
        {
            input.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
        });
        client.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived;
        client.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await client.Connect("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", TokenType.Bot);
        });
    }

    static async private void Client_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Text == "no u")
            await e.Channel.SendMessage("You have the mentality of a five year old");
    }
}
```